# iOS: scrollToRowAtIndexPath not scrolling correctly...because of the insets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've finally got my method working that when the keyboard is shown, my table view moves up.
 All my cells contain one **textfield** and some **labels** around it. So far the original method (and this one as well strangely...) **scroll only so far that the textfield is visible not whole cell**.

But why? I want the whole cell scrolled up. Did I miscalculate the insets? I don't think so though...all my views have a tableview and a footer view (height 55) below that table view. Some have a header (height 80) above the table as well. But in neither of them does it scroll the entire cell into view, only the textfield.
The atScrollPosition parameter has zero influence and it scrolls always the same..

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    //All table views are embedded in the parent view
    //The parent view y is defined by the status and navigation bar, the height by the tab bar
    CGRect viewRect = self.view.frame;
    CGRect tableRect = self.tableView.frame;

    //The keyboard size will be adjusted that the height is really only the height overlapping the table
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbOriginalSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGFloat effectiveKeyBoardHeight = kbOriginalSize.height - TABBARHEIGHT - (viewRect.size.height - tableRect.size.height - tableRect.origin.y); //the last origin property is important to find out if there is a header
    if(effectiveKeyBoardHeight < 0) effectiveKeyBoardHeight = 0;
    CGSize kbSize = CGSizeMake(kbOriginalSize.width, effectiveKeyBoardHeight);

    //Now the content insets will be adjusted for the calculated part of the keyboard overlapping the table
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // I've changed the apple code here! They use viewRect..in my app this doesn't make any sense, tableRect is key
    tableRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(tableRect, self.activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        //[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:cell.frame animated:YES];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForCellContainingUIElement:self.activeField] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked the cell's frame ?

Comment: Yes, cell's frame seems fine...I mean width, height etc. I also tried [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:cell.frame]. Same result. When I adjust the contentInset by 30 pixel more everything seems to work, but I don't understand why. Without these additional 30 pixels my table is large enough and everything calculated correctly

Comment: Did you find any solution to it ?